# XLib font size too small?

Tags: c++, fonts, font-size, xlib

currently I'm using this font in my C++ program:

```
-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-15
```

where '12', the size, is also the font size I'm using currently with Linux Mint 18-1.
But when I draw in my program a string it is shown *very* small! It looks like it has a size of '6'!

Do I need to double the font size for my program, or something like that?

TIA
Regards
Earlybite

Comment: I simply hadn't set XSetFont...

Comment: OK, thanks f0r your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching some hours the internet, also here, but I couldn't find an solution. Also in my "pre-version" of my program, I couldn't find the difference, because *there was a normal drawing with XLib and DrawString.

I also noticed, that even size = 40 hadn't a difference to e.g. size = 20. So there had to be a difference in coding.

So I went through the pre-version code line by line and at least I found that little line: XSetFont().
Which makes drawing strings normal.

E.g. like that:

```
XSetFont(mDisplay, vGC, this->mFontPtr.fid); // <-- HERE!
vGCVal.foreground = mXForeColorA->X_Color.pixel;
XChangeGC(mDisplay,vGC, GCForeground, &vGCVal);
XDrawString(mDisplay, vPix, vGC, x, y, nDrawString.c_str(), (int) nDrawString.length());
```